# Integral extension of a local ring is semilocal

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-rings, cohen-macaulay

> Let $S\subseteq R$ be commutative rings with $1$. It is given that $S$ is local and $R$ is integral over $S$. I need to show that $R$ is semilocal that is $R$ has finitely many maximal ideals.

It is also given that $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay (if you need that). But I don't see how this will be useful. Assume it is also given that both $R$ and $S$ are Noetherian.

I don't know if we can conclude from the above conditions whether $R$ is semilocal or not. But if we include another assumption that: for each ideal $I\subseteq S$, $IR\cap S=I$, then $R$ is semilocal. This assumption was given in my case which I didn't realize first.

Using the above additional hypothesis $S/\mathfrak m\subseteq R/\mathfrak mR$ and the extension is integral. But $S/\mathfrak m$ is a field and hence $R/\mathfrak mR$ is Artinian and so it has finitely many maximal ideals. Since maximal ideals of $R$ must contain $\mathfrak mR$, we conclude that $R$ is semilocal. (Above $\mathfrak m$  is the maximal ideal of $S$.)

Comment: Stupid observation/reformulation: let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the unique maximal ideal of $S$. Since $R$ is integral over $S$, the intersection of any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ of $R$ with $S$ is maximal, hence equal to $\mathfrak{m}$. In other words, the maximal ideals of $R$ are precisely the elements of the fiber over $\mathfrak{m}$ of the induced map $\mathrm{Spec}(R) \to \mathrm{Spec}(S)$. Hence, it suffices to show that this fiber over $\mathfrak{m}$ is finite. Unfortunately, I don't see any route to proceed with this reformulation, but maybe someone will.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Comment: The maximal ideals of $R$ lie over $m$ (the maximal ideal of $S$) and are minimal over $mR$. If $R$ is Noetherian then you are done.

Comment: Btw, $R$ noetherian is necessary. Otherwise there are counter-examples.

Comment: @user26857  how do you conclude $R$  Noetherian implies we are done?

Comment: I have included another assumption and solved it myself. So should I delete the question?

Comment: @Rtk427 Rather than delete it, you can answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @Rtk427 In a noetherian ring there are only finitely many minimal ideals over a given ideal.